# Applying style by TargetType, if style connected in App.xaml

Tags: .net, wpf, styles, targettype

For example, I have style

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
...
</Style>
```

in file Button.xaml
If I add this style using MergeDictionary in file where i want to use it - all working good. But if i connect this style higher in the hierarchy of files (for example in App.xaml) style stop working until i set x:Key for it and for all button set

> Style="{StaticResource name_of_style}".

Can i avoid this behavior or I must set for all my elements style by name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting it as an application resource within your app.xaml, you can also do the same thing when calling specific styles to specific views if you do the same to the UserControl.Resources of your view.

PS - Example is silverlight, but method remains the same.

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
              x:Class="The.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource name_of_style}"/>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Yes, this working, thank you. But interesting, why it not working why i append style with this code `<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Gui;component/Themes/GrayLightBM/Theme.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>`

Comment: Could your path string be incorrect so it's not actually finding your Resource Dictionary? Also is your ResourceDictionary set of type <ResourceDictionary with the proper build action properties etc? Also if the resource dictionary is in a different project within your solution, do you have that project referenced so it can find it? Just some additional ideas...

Comment: No, all correct, because i can use appended styles by its names.