# VS 2012 App.xaml Implicit Styling Issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I'm designing an application in C# and XAML based on MahApps.Metro open-source toolkit while working in the Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 IDE. Everything works fine except for implicitly defined styles referenced within the App.xaml file. The code for the resource dictionary in the App.xaml file looks like this:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApplication"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/MainDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

And the code within the MainDictionary.xaml file looks like this:

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedSingleRowTabControl.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/stringTable.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/controls.styles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

The Controls.xaml file in the MahApps.Metro project contains many implicit defines for almost every standard control available (Reference the [Git/Source](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/master/MahApps.Metro) for the code), along with some color/theme defines. This is the Dictionary that's breaking.

This format works fine in my MainWindow.xaml file, where all the implicit styles work normally on all of the default controls, but breaks when it is located within my App.xaml file. I can still access all of the Resources (using DynamicResource) within the ResourceDictionaries when it is loaded within my App.xaml file, and I can even define styles explicitly on controls, so by that logic I can trace down the issue to something to do with implicit declarations within the App.xaml file.

I've found a few related issues ([Reference One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278701/applying-style-by-targettype-if-style-connected-in-app-xaml)), but none with a viable or working solution available.

This is fully reproducible in a test application with MahApps.Metro installed (Reference: http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) a window, some random controls, and all of the ResourceDictionary references located within the App.xaml file.

Another weird thing about this is that in the VS 2012 XAML Designer view, all of the implicitly defined controls and colors load correctly, but as soon as the application is started it breaks (but does not crash or output any errors).

For this project I need these resources to be available globally (on all files in the project), so if there is another way to do that besides using the App.xaml file I would be willing to give it a try.

Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be a known issue, in addition to your link there's [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753651/wpf-not-applying-default-styles-defined-in-mergeddictionaries) about this. Christian Moser's answer on that question (add dummy styles based on the default ones to the dictionary/app) seems like the only reasonably workaround. It'd be interesting if someone knew why this happens. Also, really interesting project, I'll probably be looking at using it in the future if I can, seems great.

Comment: @dylanplecki, did you ever get the solution to this?